# Sailsjs - Prevent non-model fileds to be saved in mongo document

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo

I recently started working with **Sails** and **mongo**.
I use **Sails** blueprints to generate part of my api.
The problem is, that the request body I send is being saved to the mongo collection, regardless of the fields defined in the model.

So for example, let's say I have the following **Event** model:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    title: {
     type: 'string',
     required: true
    },
  } 
}
```

When I Send a POST request to the **/event/** endpoint with the following params:

```
{"title":"Some Event", "random":"string"}
```

The saved mongo document contains also the **"random":"string"** value, even though it's not part of the model.

I've tried to come up with some common method to remove non-model attributes before creation for all models, but the possible solutions seemed not right and dirty.

Am I missing something?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `schema` option in your model. Just add it to model declaration and that's it.

```
// api/models/Model.js
module.exports = {
  schema: true,
  attributes: {
    title: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    }
  }
};
```